# background push notification in ionic3

Tags: push-notification, ionic3

I have completed an e-commerce app in ionic3. The problem is I want user to be notified when new offers or deals are added in our inventory. This should be a backend process, whether or not the app is open or close.
Note: There is no firebase involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use to get notification in same device then you can try [Local notification](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/) native plugin for notification and if you want to send notification to other device then you have to use [Push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/push/) or [FCM](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/fcm/) or [Onesignal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/) and yes this all required firebase to send push notification to generate device id/key.